# How to change the color of *just* the header?

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-sdk, qml

Is there a non-hacky way to change the color of *just* the header in an app using the Ubuntu SDK? `MainView` has a `headerColor` property, but that is used as the first step of gradient. Currently, I'm just putting a colored rectangle up there:

```
Rectangle {
    id: headerBackground
    height: header.height
    width: header.width
    anchors.top: parent.top
    color: "#288369"
}
```

But this causes a number of issues, most notably it is incomparable with a `ListView` that fills an entire page. A full example can be found in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/andrewsomething/9294239).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Michael's pointer to Karma Machine's implementation did indeed point me in the right direction. The key is injecting the rectangle into the header so that it is a proper child. This can be done with the [createObject() method](http://developer.ubuntu.com/api/qml/sdk-14.04/QtQml.Component/#createObject-method) that Michael mentioned if you have the rectangle in a separate qml file, or you can use [createQmlObject](http://developer.ubuntu.com/api/qml/sdk-14.04/QtQml.Qt/#createQmlObject-method) with a string of QML.

Below is a much simplified example (using Tabs but the same thing is possible with a PageStack):

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import Ubuntu.Components 0.1

MainView {
    id: mainView

    width: units.gu(40)
    height: units.gu(60)

    Tabs {
        id: tabs

        Tab {
            title: i18n.tr("Colored Header")
            page: Page {
            }
        }
    }

    Component.onCompleted: {
        tabs.tabBar.__styleInstance.headerTextSelectedColor = "white";
        var component = Qt.createQmlObject(
            'import QtQuick 2.0; Rectangle { anchors.fill: parent; z: -1; color: "#288369"; }',
            tabs.header);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try setting `anchors.fill: header`, that way it always stays within the bounds of the Header component.

You can also check out a more detailed implementation from KarmaMachine:

At the bottom here the developer creates a new HeaderArea component that is a child of pageStack.header
https://github.com/brianrobles204/Karma-Machine/blob/master/KarmaMachine.qml#L489

using the QML Component.createObject() method from:
http://developer.ubuntu.com/api/qml/sdk-14.04/QtQml.Component/#createObject-method

Then in the HeaderArea he sets the anchors to fill the parent, which is pageStack.header:
https://github.com/brianrobles204/Karma-Machine/blob/master/HeaderArea.qml#L19

He also does a lot more to add functionality to the header, but it should give you an idea of how to do it.

Comment: Thanks. The KarmaMachine example looks like it will point me in the right direction. Unfortunately, using `anchors.fill: header` still has the same problem with a ListView. See: https://gist.github.com/andrewsomething/9294239